# visualforce page problem on home page layout in salesforce

Tags: home-page-layout

Visualforce page is displaying on home page layout. It used to work previously but all of a sudden we found that it is not showing. Could find the reason we checked the home page layout and component and even tried to delete and create a new one but no luck

Comment: Where are you trying? Classic or lightning?

Comment: Its is in Classic

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your responses.

It worked for when I added showHeader=false @ page level in visualforce page

Comment: There aren't currently any other responses on this question. @Jaya, could you expand on your question and/or answer to show the code that was problematic and your solution? That would provide more value to the community.